# Creating new rails app dumps all the information in root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am having a strange issue. When I do rails new ~ whatever it creates all the files put slews them across my root directory in OSX. Even when I have specified to start in a different directory, it always places it all there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you literally typing:

```
rails new ~ whatever
```

the rails command has the following usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

So it looks to me like you're trying to create a new rails app in your home dir. Try:

```
rails new whatever
```

Comment: Oh, that is my issue. Shooooooot. Thanks!